# How to pass a csv file as a parameter to a sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

I have a script which needs inputs from a csv file saved in GIT. I don't want to import the csv file as a table in the database. How can I pass the csv file as an input parameter to the sql script?

Comment: What language/script are you using to run your sql scripts into the database? If you are just running a .sql file into your database by way of a command line or sql client UI then you'll need to write some code to manipulate your .sql file to pick up the values from your csv and apply them into the .sql file. You'll have to share a lot more information here (sample of the csv file, sample of the .sql file, RDBMS you are using, etc.).

Comment: you could pass it in a variable, but you'll likely still end up parsing it into a table whether temporary, variable or permanent